# Dictionary like implementation in C/C++ (Update info)

Tags: c++, c, dictionary

Does anyone have information or example of how to mount the equivalent of a Dictionary (VB6) in C or C++ ?
This implementation is used to be passed as a parameter called DLL VB6.

My intention is to create a Dictionary in C (win32 using VARIANT/ARRAYs, etc) and pass it to call a VB. So I have to learn how to create this data structure.

Tanks.

Comment: "This implementation is used to be passed as a parameter called DLL VB6". Could you explain this better? It sounds a bit confusing to me.

Answer (score 9):

How about a [map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/)?

Answer (score 6):

The next version of C++ will have `unordered_map<>` (apparently they thought that calling it `hash_map` would conflict with too many independent implementations), which will be a hash-based container.

It was added to Boost, and is likely to be in TR1.  As always, if your development system doesn't support the new standard features, I recommend Boost.

Answer (score 5):

Dictionary is hash based, map is a tree based container. I think tr1 added a hash container of some sort but on a lot of platforms you can use [hash_map](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/hash_map.html)

Answer (score 3):

You mean besides `std::map` in the [map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/) header?

Answer (score 2):

A hash table? You can find several existing hash table packages in C, for instance:

- [Glib](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/stable/glib-Hash-Tables.html) Very common, [well documented](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/stable/glib-Hash-Tables.html) and easy to use.
- [HashIt](http://freshmeat.net/projects/hashit/)
- [Judy](http://judy.sourceforge.net/)

You can also use a package made for permanent storage, since some have an option to keep everything in memory for speed.

- [HamsterDB](http://hamsterdb.com/) "in memory database", option HAM_IN_MEMORY_DB
- [BerkeleyDB](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/berkeley-db/db/index.html), may be by [switching buffering off](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/berkeley-db/faq/db_faq.html#34) or specifying no file ("In-memory databases never intended to be preserved on disk may be created by setting the file parameter to NULL.")